# C++ Segmentation Fault. GDB and Valgrind output included

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

Compiled on Ubuntu Bionic 10/2018 ARM 64bit with clang.

Error: Segmentation fault.

Any ideas?

```
for (t = ta_args(ta); t; t = (tagi_t )t_next(t)) {
    tag_type_t tt = t->t_tag;

    if (!tt)
        continue;

    if (tt->tt_class == ref_tag_class) {
        assert(((tag_type_t)tt->tt_magic)->tt_class->tc_ref_set);
        n += tl_get(tt, (void )t->t_value, lst);
    }
#if !defined(NDEBUG)
    else if (tt->tt_class && tt->tt_class->tc_ref_set) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: tag %s::%s directly used by tl_gets()\n",
            tt->tt_ns ? tt->tt_ns : "", tt->tt_name ? tt->tt_name : "");
        assert(tt->tt_class == ref_tag_class);
    }
#endif
}

ta_end(ta);
```

GDB output:

```
(gdb) where
#0 0x0000007fb77128a8 in tl_gets (lst=, tag=, value=)
at su_taglist.c:412
(gdb) list 400,430
400
401 for (t = ta_args(ta); t; t = (tagi_t )t_next(t)) {
402 tag_type_t tt = t->t_tag;
403
404 if (!tt)
405 continue;
406
407 if (tt->tt_class == ref_tag_class) {
408 assert(((tag_type_t)tt->tt_magic)->tt_class->tc_ref_set);
409 n += tl_get(tt, (void )t->t_value, lst);
410 }
411 #if !defined(NDEBUG)
412 else if (tt->tt_class && tt->tt_class->tc_ref_set) {
413 fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: tag %s::%s directly used by tl_gets()\n",
414 tt->tt_ns ? tt->tt_ns : "", tt->tt_name ? tt->tt_name : "");
415 assert(tt->tt_class == ref_tag_class);
416 }
417 #endif
418 }
419
420 ta_end(ta);
421
422 return n;
423 }
424
425 / Find tags from given list.
426 *
427 * Copies values of argument tag list into the reference tags in the tag
428 * list @A lst.
429 *
430 * @sa tl_gets()
(gdb) print tt
$5 = (tag_type_t) 0x7fb7e5123e
(gdb) print tt_class
No symbol "tt_class" in current context.
(gdb) print tt->tt_class
$6 = (tag_class_t *) 0x78656c4600736e69
(gdb) print tt->tt_class->tc_ref_set
Cannot access memory at address 0x78656c4600736eb9
```

Valgrind output:

```
==5631== Syscall param epoll_ctl(event) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==5631==    at 0x70E4CD8: epoll_ctl (syscall-template.S:78)
==5631==    by 0x51997E7: su_epoll_port_register (su_epoll_port.c:256)
==5631==    by 0x519850F: su_port_register (su_port.h:280)
==5631==    by 0x519850F: su_socket_port_init (su_socket_port.c:143)
==5631==    by 0x5199E17: su_epoll_port_create (su_epoll_port.c:558)
==5631==    by 0x5193E6F: su_root_create (su_root.c:409)
==5631==    by 0x438D0F: main (main.cc:885)
==5631==  Address 0x1ffeffc6a4 is on thread 1's stack
==5631==  in frame #1, created by su_epoll_port_register (su_epoll_port.c:202)
==5631== 
==5631== Invalid read of size 8
==5631==    at 0x519C8A8: tl_gets (su_taglist.c:412)
==5631==    by 0x51A2A5F: tport_set_params (tport.c:1369)
==5631==    by 0x51A2723: tport_tcreate (tport.c:554)
==5631==    by 0x51C4A57: he_create_tports (nth_client.c:456)
==5631==    by 0x51C4A57: nth_engine_create (nth_client.c:299)
==5631==    by 0x4C20417: Agent::Agent(su_root_s*) (agent.cc:589)
==5631==    by 0x45D4AF: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Agent>::construct<Agent, su_root_s*&>(Agent*, su_root_s*&) (new_allocator.h:136)
==5631==    by 0x45D1E7: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Agent> >::construct<Agent, su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent>&, Agent*, su_root_s*&) (alloc_traits.h:475)
==5631==    by 0x45CF17: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:526)
==5631==    by 0x45CB9F: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, Agent*, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:637)
==5631==    by 0x45CA97: std::__shared_ptr<Agent, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1294)
==5631==    by 0x45C9F7: std::shared_ptr<Agent>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:344)
==5631==    by 0x45C92B: std::shared_ptr<Agent> std::allocate_shared<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:690)
==5631==  Address 0x78656c4600736eb9 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5631== 
==5631== 
==5631== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==5631==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x656C4600736EB9
==5631==    at 0x519C8A8: tl_gets (su_taglist.c:412)
==5631==    by 0x51A2A5F: tport_set_params (tport.c:1369)
==5631==    by 0x51A2723: tport_tcreate (tport.c:554)
==5631==    by 0x51C4A57: he_create_tports (nth_client.c:456)
==5631==    by 0x51C4A57: nth_engine_create (nth_client.c:299)
==5631==    by 0x4C20417: Agent::Agent(su_root_s*) (agent.cc:589)
==5631==    by 0x45D4AF: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Agent>::construct<Agent, su_root_s*&>(Agent*, su_root_s*&) (new_allocator.h:136)
==5631==    by 0x45D1E7: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Agent> >::construct<Agent, su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent>&, Agent*, su_root_s*&) (alloc_traits.h:475)
==5631==    by 0x45CF17: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:526)
==5631==    by 0x45CB9F: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, Agent*, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:637)
==5631==    by 0x45CA97: std::__shared_ptr<Agent, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1294)
==5631==    by 0x45C9F7: std::shared_ptr<Agent>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:344)
==5631==    by 0x45C92B: std::shared_ptr<Agent> std::allocate_shared<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:690)
==5631==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5631==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==5631==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5631==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5631==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.

valgrind: m_coredump/coredump-elf.c:495 (fill_fpu): Assertion 'Unimplemented functionality' failed.
valgrind: valgrind

host stacktrace:
==5631==    at 0x5803DBD0: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-arm64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 5631)
==5631==    at 0x519C8A8: tl_gets (su_taglist.c:412)
==5631==    by 0x51A2A5F: tport_set_params (tport.c:1369)
==5631==    by 0x51A2723: tport_tcreate (tport.c:554)
==5631==    by 0x51C4A57: he_create_tports (nth_client.c:456)
==5631==    by 0x51C4A57: nth_engine_create (nth_client.c:299)
==5631==    by 0x4C20417: Agent::Agent(su_root_s*) (agent.cc:589)
==5631==    by 0x45D4AF: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Agent>::construct<Agent, su_root_s*&>(Agent*, su_root_s*&) (new_allocator.h:136)
==5631==    by 0x45D1E7: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Agent> >::construct<Agent, su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent>&, Agent*, su_root_s*&) (alloc_traits.h:475)
==5631==    by 0x45CF17: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:526)
==5631==    by 0x45CB9F: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, Agent*, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:637)
==5631==    by 0x45CA97: std::__shared_ptr<Agent, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1294)
==5631==    by 0x45C9F7: std::shared_ptr<Agent>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:344)
==5631==    by 0x45C92B: std::shared_ptr<Agent> std::allocate_shared<Agent, std::allocator<Agent>, su_root_s*&>(std::allocator<Agent> const&, su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:690)
==5631==    by 0x440DC7: std::shared_ptr<Agent> std::make_shared<Agent, su_root_s*&>(su_root_s*&) (shared_ptr.h:706)
==5631==    by 0x438D3B: main (main.cc:890)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Your GDB output shows a listing of the code you already gave and some variable inspections, but it is not clear at what point in your code this was done.  You should perhaps run til the seg-fault, GDB will tell you at what line that occurred, and then and there inspect the variables involved.

Comment: gdb and valgrind - I was summarising, but my post with nice format was refused. Now it seems ok. Indent - what do you want to indent here? This is debugging output, not code. I'm happy to do anything needed. For newcomer to stack - post writing is really not friendly. Just sharing my experience. Happy to learn all.

Comment: `tt->tt_class->tc_ref_set` seems to contain garbage. You need to trace back to where it is (or isn't) initialized.

Comment: @KarolisMarksaitis my (now deleted) answer was wrong. Forget about it. Sorry.

Comment: @Jabberwocky no worries.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I figured that this contains some nonsense in gdb. The issue is that I don't know what to do next to solve this. I want to fix this for myself and also post a commit to github to help other people. I just don't know on the next step.

Comment: Where is the code that populates `tt->tt_class`? That'll be a good place to start looking

Comment: @ChrisTurner I searched repo. I don't understand what populates it? https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/sofia-sip/search?q=tt-%3Ett_class&unscoped_q=tt-%3Ett_class

Answer (score 0):

> `Address 0x78656c4600736eb9 is not stack'd`

One of the two pointers that are dereferenced contains garbage. The garbage here actually spells `"ns\0Flex"` in `ASCII`.

This could be due to stack buffer overflow, a data race, reading uninitialized memory, or access to freeed and reallocated memory.

Your best bet is to instrumented the source with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (`-fsanitize=address`), and report the problem to developers.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I will try what you say. Though the code is from 2005 used in belle-sip module and made from nokia. It's all part of flexisip program. Another strange thing is that it compiles and run's with same config just fine on x86. So I am thinking, how the hell it works on x86 and does not on ARM? Any clue for how this can happen?

Comment: @KarolisMarksaitis It is *very* common for new bugs to be exposed when a package is moved to a different architecture. An uninitialized value *just happens* to be 0 most of the time on x86, and not on ARM (or vice versa).

Comment: Interesting. So different. Is it then not possible to make uninitialised values to be 0 by default on ARM? This would simply solve the issue. Thanks for advising!

Comment: @KarolisMarksaitis No, it's not possible to make uninitialized value to be anything -- that's what uninitialized *means*. If it were zero by default, that would make it initialized.

Comment: Okok, but it seems that already there is some default value set for ARM and x86! As they are different :) So whats easiest way to deal with it? Can I just initialise my problematic struct to 0 at the beginning of source code file? Thanks for advice!

Comment: @KarolisMarksaitis There *isn't* a default uninitialized value on either ARM of x86. The easiest way to deal with this is to find and fix the bug. Whether that involves initializing something to 0, or fixing a dangling pointer reference, or something else *requires* finding the bug first.

Comment: But if its some value on x86 and different one on ARM, what sets it? Also, what is “dangling pointer reference”?

Comment: @KarolisMarksaitis You appear to not understand what unitialized means. *Nothing* sets that value, it just happens to be whatever was there before (from some unrelated use of that memory earlier).

Comment: Well I get that part. But then what sort of coincidence makes this value 0 always on x86 and !0 on ARM? Im talking theory based on your input. Also, code in my post line 412 https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/sofia-sip/blob/bc/libsofia-sip-ua/su/su_taglist.c seems to be running only if “#if !defined(NDEBUG)” is true. So im trying to just remove this section as it’s purely for debugging if I understand correctly.